# Multi thread lock requirements

Tags: multithreading

I had this as an interview question a while back, but I wasn't sure of the answer.

If you calculate c = c+1 with 100 threads, do you need a lock?

Comment: I think that would depend on the language/memory model

Comment: Yes; but you can use `Interlocked` (or other atomic implementation) to avoid locking

Comment: if i were you, i set critical section instead of lock. Because all threads work same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The reason is that the statement `c = c + 1` is  actually (about) three low level statements:

```
1. read c from the memory
2. increment c by one
3. store c back to the memory
```

If two threads execute `(1)`, they will both increment `c` to the same value and store it. So instead of being incremented twice, `c` will be incremented only once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in pretty much every programming language that supports concurrency.